# Changes in object-mode are not carried over to the slicer

Tags: modeling, mesh, modifiers, export

I thought I solved my problem by adding *Triangulate* modifier. It only worked on one object. I have made a round base plate using a cylinder. I have pushed a smaller cylinder through and created a hole using *Boolean* modifier in the base plate, applied, hide and add *Triangulate*.

Everything works, there is a hole in the plate, but after exporting the stl file to the slicer, the two cylinders are on top of each other. What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Please add an [image](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post) of your object in Blender and possibly share your Blend file via https://blend-exchange.com/ following the instructions on that page.

Comment: Hiding an object in the viewport does not keep it from being exported to STL. You have to either select only the object with the hole and enable _Selection Only_ in the export dialogue or you have to delete the object you don't want to be exported.

Comment: Thanks so much for the advice - looking forward to trying it out

Answer (score 0):

Ensure `Selection Only` and `Apply Modifiers` are both checked.
[image]

An easier way is to use the 3D Printing Toolbox that comes with blender, you have to activate it in the addons section in Preferences. It includes a lot of other useful tools for checking your models for 3D printing as well.

Comment: Thanks so much for the advice - looking forward to trying it out